# trouble handling strings with three or more '0' using pgloader

Tags: postgresql, pgloader

I am loading large .csv files into a database and want to use pgloader because it is able to skip and log erroneous records. However I frequently get

`ERROR PostgreSQL Database error 22021: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00`

Which I first thought was due to `0x00` characters in my data. I tried different ways to remove these to no avail, until I noticed that some variables e.g. timestamps with three or more `0`characters seem to be causing the problem. e.g. `17:46:30 +0000`. Does anyone know how to handle this problem without changing my data? About 2/3 of my records have this problem. Ideally I am looking for a fix that allows me to import the data using the same procedure.

Comment: It's not a "0" character. Your first idea was correct - there are zero-valued bytes in the data stream

Comment: What would a good way to go about removing these @RichardHuxton? Trying sed and tr did not work for me then

Comment: Are you sure the file is actually UTF-8 and not some other encoding? That is the first thing to check.